# Installing exe installation file on a remote server using PsExec

Tags: deployment, remote-server, psexec, windows-installer, advanced-installer

I'm trying to install an exe installation file using PsExec:
PsExec targetServer /s /accepteula exeFilePath /i /quiet

For some reason I get the 1619 error.
I'm running as an admin and my user is an admin on the remote server.

Does anyone Know why I get this Error?

Comment: Im running on Windows Server 2008 r2

Answer (score 0):

1619 means "Database could not be opened". In other words for your case: The path of the (a) MSI file is not correct.
Probably this is a problem of finding the current directory path. Think of writing a wrapper which sets this.

But I see another potential problem:
I have not used PsExec on my own, but with UAC you have a real problem. Being an admin on a server is of no use, if UAC is activated, then nobody can commit UAC.
How about that. Being the real user named "Administrator" (not the same as being in the administrator group) or switching off UAC could help too.

You can search on stackoverflow on PsExec, there are a number of questions concerning this too.
There seem to exist a "-h" switch, but it is not sure, if it still works.

(Moreover, to be sure: You are sure, the installation exist on the remote server? psexec does not copy your files to other servers..)

Clean solutions with UAC require the involvement of services, the most easiest is the built-in task scheduler which can start also batch files with system rights, which trigger for events you can start remotely.